# Mapbox GL: Add GeoTiff to Map without uploading to Mapbox

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I have a GeoTiff file taken by a drone and I want to add it as a layer on my map using .addSource() and it doesn't seem to work.

```
mapboxMap.addSource("satellite", {
    type: "raster",
    url: "http://localhost:3000/images/satellite.tif",
  });
```

Is uploading to Mapbox the only way to implement a GeoTiff to my Map?

The .png I tested before worked fine, both files are in the public folder right now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation says, the `raster` type is:

> A raster tile source.

Note the *tile* bit.

If you want a non-tiled raster source, you want to use the `image` type. I'm not certain if Mapbox GL JS supports TIFF, and whether it supports GeoTIFF. You may need to provide the coordinates explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I created a maptiler Server to upload converted GeoTIFFs and now it works just fine!